# Videos displayed using youtube API (recycler view) play only horizontally, no vertical orientation

Tags: android, video, android-recyclerview, youtube-api

I have developed a custom application to show youtube videos  using recycler views. The videos show fine, but on clicking play orientation of the video changes to horizontal even if the direction of the phone is unchanged .

There are 3 videos for sample and all of them are stacked vertically however on trying to play, the orientation changes to horizontal (full screen). Somebody who can help me with a solution for this please.

Thank you 
Vibhav

Recycler and View Holder code:

```
    package com.example.android.kanchikamakshiammanandperiva;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.content.res.Resources;
            import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
            import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.widget.ImageView;
            import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
            import android.widget.Toast;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.net.Uri;
            import android.gesture.Gesture;
            import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
            import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
            import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeStandalonePlayer;
            import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailLoader;
            import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView;

            import static android.R.attr.data;
            import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;

    /**
     * Created by Rajan.V on 08-04-2017.
     */
    public class RecyclerActivity extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerActivity.VideoInfoHolder> {

        //these ids are the unique id for each video
        String[] VideoID = {"R1YSjGzUo-w","ROoMBKX7264"};
        Context ctx;
        String key="AIzaSyDNTmnhwyDEGEQMkZmqpc8IHb-jXytG4WE";

        public RecyclerActivity(Context context) {
            this.ctx = context;

        }

        @Override
        public VideoInfoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            return new VideoInfoHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoInfoHolder holder, final int position) {


            final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener  onThumbnailLoadedListener = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener(){
                @Override
                public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                    Log.i("onThumbnailError1","onThumbnailError1");
                }

                @Override
                public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {

                    youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.i("onThumbnailLoaded1","onThumbnailLoaded1");
                }
            };



            holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize("AIzaSyDNTmnhwyDEGEQMkZmqpc8IHb-jXytG4WE", new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VideoID[position]);
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
                    Log.i("success1","success1");
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                    Log.i("failure1","failure1");

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return VideoID.length;
        }

        public class VideoInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
            YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
            protected ImageView playButton;


            public VideoInfoHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                Log.i("VideoInfoHolder","VideoInfoHolder");
                playButton=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
                playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
                youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("onClick","onClick");
    try {
        Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx, "AIzaSyDNTmnhwyDEGEQMkZmqpc8IHb-jXytG4WE", VideoID[getLayoutPosition()]);

        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

        } }}
```

List Item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="550dp"
            android:background="@color/color_background_transparent"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/btnYoutube_player"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                android:src="@drawable/ic_youtube_play_button"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your code. without code can't help.

Comment: Edited my question to add the layout and Java code

Comment: Can i use a play list instead of using a String array as you have seen from my code i have used a string array to hold the video ids can i replace the array with a playlist , without having to change the layout etc .Can you please help me if possible.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to set lightboxMode parameter to true.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeStandalonePlayer

Comment: @Vibhav if you think it is right answer please accept as right answer.

Comment: yes it did work , unfortunately my upcast does not show up , i accept it as a right answer

Answer (score 0):

I worked on youtube api 3 to fetch playlist videos's detail:

```
 public void videoFromPlaylist() {

    AsyncHttpClient ascny = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50" + "&playlistId=" + PLAYLIST ID HERE + "&key=" + YOUR YOUTUBE API KEY;
    Log.e("URL",URL);
    ascny.get(Splash.this, URL, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            Log.e("Respnce", ">>>" + response);

            ArrayList<VideoWrapper> videoList=new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray videos = new JSONArray();

            try {


                videos = response.getJSONArray("items");
                for (int i = 0; i < videos.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject Yplaylist = videos.getJSONObject(i);

                    VideoWrapper videoWrapper = new VideoWrapper();

                    videoWrapper.setVideoId(Yplaylist.getString("id"));
                    JSONObject snippet = Yplaylist.getJSONObject("snippet");
                    videoWrapper.setTitle(snippet.getString("title"));
                    videoWrapper.setDesc(snippet.getString("description"));


                    Locale.setDefault(Locale.getDefault());
                    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
                    sdf.setCalendar(cal);
                    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(snippet.getString("publishedAt")));
                    Date date = cal.getTime();

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
                    videoWrapper.setDate(sdf2.format(date));


                    JSONObject thumbnail = snippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                    JSONObject high = thumbnail.getJSONObject("high");

                    videoWrapper.setCoverLink(high.getString("url"));
                    videoWrapper.setPlaylistID(snippet.getString("playlistId"));
                    JSONObject resource = snippet.getJSONObject("resourceId");

                    videoWrapper.setVideoId(resource.getString("videoId"));

                    videoList.add(videoWrapper);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("Video",videos.length()+"");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

            Log.e("Respnce", ">>>" + responseString);
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {

            Log.e("Respnce", ">>>" + errorResponse);
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
        }
    });


}
```